# Get value from multiple checkbox and input to an array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

How we can get the value of checkbox an input to an array?

Here is my code, I've tried this:

```
<cbComp
   v-for="name in names"
   v-bind:key="name"
   v-model="selected_name[name]">
   <span> {{ name }} </span>
</cbComp>

Name: {{ selected_name }}
```

```
data () {
    return {
      names: ['Michael', 'Millie', 'Brown'],
      selected_name: []
    }
},
```

This was the `cbComp` template:

```
<template>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input
      :id="cb"
      type="checkbox"
      :value="modelValue"
      v-model="computedValue"
    >
    <label
      :for="cb">
      <slot/>
    </label>
  </label>
</template>
```

This is the javascript:

```
export default {
  data: {
    updateValue: this.value
  },
  props: {
    value: undefined,
    modelValue: {
      type: undefined,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedValue: {
      get () {
        return this.updateValue
      },
      set (value) {
        this.updateValue = value
        this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value (value) {
      this.updateValue = value
    }
  }
}
```

It turns out there is no error, and the selected name won't appear on `{{ selected_name }}`

Comment: where is the template code for checkbox ?

Comment: Already edited above

Comment: @ariana are you supposed to be able to select multiple names as it appears you are trying to do here? If not, what should happen when a user selects multiple checkboxes? It seems like you should be using radio buttons instead.

Comment: Yea, so what I expect is when we select the checkbox, then the selected checkbox value/text will be appear inside the array @maxshuty

Comment: @ariana but do you expect multiple to be able to be selected? So where you have `Name: {{ selected_name }}` it would actually show multiple names?

Comment: Yupp, thats true, its allow multiple select @maxshuty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to bind your `v-model` to the `selected_name` property. Here is a bare minimum example for you to work off of:

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <p>Names: {{ selected_name.join(', ') }}</p>

  <label for="maxCheckbox">Max</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Max" v-model="selected_name" id="maxCheckbox">
  
  <label for="markCheckbox">Mark</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Mark" v-model="selected_name" id="markCheckbox">
 
  <label for="johnCheckbox">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="John" v-model="selected_name" id="johnCheckbox">
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        selected_name: []
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

As a side note, I would probably rename your `selected_name` to be more clear like `selected_names` or more commonly you'll find `selectedNames` camelCase.